# How to keep ID in dummyVars()

Tags: r, r-caret, one-hot-encoding

I would like to do transform `Gender` and `Country` using One-Hot-Encoding.
With the code below I can not create the new dataset including the `ID`

```
library(caret)    
ID<-1:10
Gender<-c("F","F","F","M","M","F","M","M","F","M")
Country<-c("Mali","France","France","Guinea","Senegal",
        "Mali","France","Mali","Senegal","France")
data<-data.frame(ID,Gender,Country)
#One hot encoding

dmy <- dummyVars(" ~Gender+Country", data = data, fullRank = T)

dat_transformed <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = data))

dat_transformed 

   Gender.M Country.Guinea Country.Mali Country.Senegal
1         0              0            1               0
2         0              0            0               0
3         0              0            0               0
4         1              1            0               0
5         1              0            0               1
6         0              0            1               0
7         1              0            0               0
8         1              0            1               0
9         0              0            0               1
10        1              0            0               0
```

I want to get a dataset that include the `ID` without enconding it.

```
   ID Gender.M Country.Guinea Country.Mali Country.Senegal
1   1        0              0            1               0
2   2        0              0            0               0
3   3        0              0            0               0
4   4        1              1            0               0
5   5        1              0            0               1
6   6        0              0            1               0
7   7        1              0            0               0
8   8        1              0            1               0
9   9        0              0            0               1
10 10        1              0            0               0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat_transformed <- cbind(ID,dat_transformed)

dat_transformed

   ID Gender.M Country.Guinea Country.Mali Country.Senegal
   1        0              0            1               0
   2        0              0            0               0
   3        0              0            0               0
   4        1              1            0               0
   5        1              0            0               1
   6        0              0            1               0
   7        1              0            0               0
   8        1              0            1               0
   9        0              0            0               1
  10        1              0            0               0
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I decided to do in the end. But I was afraid that merging the ID to the encoding table would create a mismatch without my realizing it